# how to use "make and building executables" in Linux work

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, executable, gnu-make

i tried to use make on my c source code and created executable file. but the executable file did not work the intended task. even if the make file compiled and produced the executable file when i try to compile the .c file individually it gave many undefined reference problem 
The errors are

```
/tmp/cc4tx0BG.o: In function `main':
cubist.c:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `Of'
cubist.c:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `Of'
cubist.c:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `Of'
cubist.c:(.text+0x10f): undefined reference to `KRInit'
cubist.c:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `ExecTime'
cubist.c:(.text+0x127): undefined reference to `PrintHeader'
cubist.c:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `Of'
[...]
cubist.c:(.text+0xb79): undefined reference to `MaxAtt'
cubist.c:(.text+0xb83): undefined reference to `InitialiseEnvData'
cubist.c:(.text+0xb8a): undefined reference to `XVAL'
cubist.c:(.text+0xb93): undefined reference to `CrossVal'
cubist.c:(.text+0xb9a): undefined reference to `SingleCttee'
cubist.c:(.text+0xb9f): undefined reference to `ExecTime'
cubist.c:(.text+0xbab): undefined reference to `Of'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

please, could any body tells how to use make and building executables in Linux work.

Comment: Cut down the output, it's understandable what's going on from first ~10 lines.

Comment: I think it's a linking error. How did you compile your source?

Comment: i used the gcc compiler to get the executable file called cubist .                 gcc -o cubist cubist.c

Comment: @melaku Is the toolchain you're using standard, or custom made? Could you also post your source cubist.c - we could probably help you better with it.

Comment: is standard toolchain. GPL edition c source code of cubist is availabile at (http://rulequest.com/download.html). you can also see the cubist.c

Answer (score 0):

I *think* (not sure) that you are saying that you successfully produced an executable using Make (at least that's how I interpret "use make on my c source code and created executable file" -- do correct me if I'm wrong!).  If that's the case, invoke make like this: `make -B --trace`, and you'll see the exact commands that were used to build the executable, and then you'll hopefully know which compiler/linker flags or libraries you missed while trying to build stuff manually.